# Are there any Chrome extensions that support Google Bookmarks "lists"

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, google-bookmarks

Are there any Chrome extensions that support Google Bookmarks "[lists](http://www.google.com/support/bookmarks/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171089)"? There are plenty of extensions that support regular Google bookmarks such as [YAGBE](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jdnejaepfmacfdmhkplckpfdcjgbeode)

Answer (score 0):

Though [jimmy's google bookmakrs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fhaicgmeeafgboeobjagfmlcdhbkijhf#) does support lists, your YAGBE suggestion seems much cooler (at least today) so I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Anyways, I prefer the much simpler [Easy Marks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhjihpkhlbkmhnjjdaekkfenhipmhpjo#).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this may be useful for you,

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ffmdedmghpoipeldijkdlcckdpempkdi?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon